# Adding a class name to every fouth item in a forloop

Tags: php

I'm used to doing this with Django and it's fairly simple, so trying to workout how it's done in PHP. What I'd like to do is within a PHP for foreach loop I would like to add the class name of 'last' to every fourth item in the list.

PHP code:

```
 <?php 
  $products = array();
  $product_counter = 0;
  foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) 
  { 

  ?>
```

So this is my current HTML output:

```
<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>


<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>


<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>


<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>
```

However, what I would like to acheive is:

```
<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="contentWrap"> content here </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="contentWrap last"> content here </div>
</li>
```

I was using the nth child attribute in CSS3 but it needs to be supported in IE8!

Anyway, PHP isn't my strong point and can't make use of the examples i've found online so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any php code to generate the "content here"/ the general layout stuff?

Comment: You could use a counter in a loop together with the % (modulo) operator.

Comment: I've now added the PHP code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
     //whatever
     if ($counter % 4 == 3) {
         //do stuff for every 4th element
     }
     $counter++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try and come back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple right?

```
for($i = 0; $i < $countOfArray; $i++) {

    if($i % 4 == 3) {
        // add last class ....
    }
}
```